# Ordered groups: do irreducible elements always commute?

Tags: group-theory, order-theory, lattice-orders, ordered-groups

The title is the main question.

Explaining the notation, an ordered group is a group $X$ with a partial order such that for every $x,y,z\in X$, if $x\leq y$, then $zx\leq zy$ and $xz\leq yz$.

An element $x\in X$ is called *irreducible* iff $e<x$ ($e$ is the neutral element) and for every $y\in X$, if $e\leq y\leq x$, then $y=e$ or $y=x$.

I already know that for any irreducible elements $x,y\in X$, if they have infimum $x\sqcap y$, then they commute.

Indeed, we have $e\leq x\sqcap y\leq x$, so $x\sqcap y=e$ or $x\sqcap y=x$. If $x\sqcap y=x$, then $e<x\leq y$, so $x=y$, so they commute. If $x\sqcap y=e$, then for every $z\in X$ we have

$(xy\leq z\Leftrightarrow e\leq x^{-1}zy^{-1}\Leftrightarrow yz^{-1}x\leq e\Leftrightarrow (yz^{-1}x\leq x\text{ and }yz^{-1}x\leq y)\Leftrightarrow (yz^{-1}\leq e\text{ and }z^{-1}x\leq e)\Leftrightarrow (y\leq z\text{ and }x\leq z))$

and analogously we have

$(yx\leq z\Leftrightarrow(x\leq z\text{ and }y\leq z))$

so both $xy$ and $yx$ are suprema of $x$ and $y$, so they are equal.

However, I have no idea about what to do if they do not have infimum.

Comment: Explain $yz^{-1}x\leq e\Rightarrow yz^{-1}x\leq x.$

Comment: If $x,y$ are irreducible, then, by definition, we have $e<x$, therefore $yz^{−1}x\leq e\Rightarrow yz^{−1}x\leq x$. Moreover, in the case $x\sqcap y=e$, if $y^{-1}zx^{-1}\leq x$ and $y^{-1}zx^{-1}\leq y$, then $y^{-1}zx^{-1}$ is a lower bound of $x$ and $y$, therefore, $y^{-1}zx^{-1}\leq e$.

Comment: Do free groups contain irreducible elements?

Comment: What partial order are you considering in the free group?

Comment: @DanielKawai Any order... In a free group nothing really commutes with anything else* so it would be weird if there were irreducible elements and they all commuted. (*or rather, if $a$ and $b$ commute then there exists some $c$ such that $c^i=a$, $c^j=b$, and there is no $d$ such that $d^n=c$ for all $|n|>1$.)

Comment: I only know about total orderings in free groups, but in this case there would be at most one irreducible element. Do you know some partial order in free group that makes at least two noncommuting irreducible elements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is No.

I will explain why, if $\Gamma$ is any nonabelian group that has a surjective group homomorphism $\varphi: \Gamma\to \mathbb Z$, there is a partial order on $\Gamma$ compatible with left/right multiplication for which some irreducible elements fail to commute.

Assume that $\Gamma$ is any nonabelian group, and that $\varphi: \Gamma\to \mathbb Z$ is a surjective group homomorphism. Define a strict partial order on $\Gamma$ by:

$F<G$ in $\Gamma$ iff $\varphi(F)<\varphi(G)$ in $\mathbb Z$

Then, of course, $F\leq G$ is defined to mean $F<G$ or $F=G$. This is a partial order on $\Gamma$, and it is compatible with left and right multiplication by elements of $\Gamma$, because the strict order on $\mathbb Z$ is compatible with left/right addition by elements of $\mathbb Z$.

The elements in $\varphi^{-1}(1)$ are irreducible in the order on $\Gamma$. The set $\varphi^{-1}(1)$ generates $\Gamma$, since $1$ generates $\mathbb Z$, so if $\Gamma$ is nonabelian then some pair of elements in $\varphi^{-1}(1)$ must fail to commute. This explains why $\Gamma$ must have a pair of noncommuting irreducible elements.

For example, if $\Gamma = F_{\textrm{Grp}}(x,y)$ is the free group over $\{x,y\}$, then we can take $\varphi:\Gamma\to \mathbb Z$ to be the map determined by $x\mapsto 1, y\mapsto 1$. Then both $x$ and $y$ are irreducible in the derived partial order, but they do not commute.

For a solvable example, take $\Gamma$ to be the group of functions $F\colon \mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ which are expressible as $F(x) = ax+b$ where $a$ is an integral power of $2$ and $b$ is a dyadic rational, and the multiplication operation of $\Gamma$ is composition of functions. Take $\varphi: \Gamma\to \mathbb Z$ to be the homomorphism $ax+b\mapsto \log_2(a)$. The functions $f(x)=2x$ and $G(x)=2x+1$ are irreducible in the derived ordering, but do not commute under composition.